# PHP LDAP Search. EmployeeID missing

Tags: php, ldap

Using PHP LDAP Search it returns tons of fields for myself but no employeeid. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a mandatory attribute. So it can be unset in the directory, so it won't be retrieved by the search.

Other possibility is that there is a constraint that prevent you to retrieve this attribute.

I'm no Active Directory expert, but there should be some mechanism to control access data. (May be the [searchFlag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679765(v=vs.85).aspx))